# Position an Document attachment in a specific position - Java Mail/Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf, jakarta-mail

I want to sent a html mail with attachment(using Thymeleaf Template) in Java
My mail is centre aligned with a left padding of 20px. I created the Thymeleaf template and able to receive the mail with attachment

Issue is

1. Attachment is left aligned. so mail contents are in centre and this .doc attachment is on the extreme left and misaligned.

How to position the attachment at a particular position in the mail. Like we position images using Thymeleaf can we position the attachment.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Images are part of mail content - attachments are not. Unless I'm gravely mistaken, what you ask for it not possible to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, so if we want to create a mail and attach a document at a certain position, it is not possible in java?

Comment: I think it's not possible in email in general. You can insert a link to download the file that is stored elsewhere on the internet, but that link can't point to an attachment, because attachment doesn't have its own URI.